# One massive CSS - or lots of little ones?

Tags: html, css

Simple question hopefully.

We have a style sheet that is over 3000 lines long and there is a noticeable lag when the page is rendering as a result.

Here's the question:  Is it better to have one massive style sheet that covers everything, or lots of little style sheets that cover different parts of the page?  (eg one for layout, one for maybe the drop down menu, one for colours etc?)

*This is for performance only, not really 'which is easier'*

Comment: Have you tried to compress the CSS file? (http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor)

Comment: silly question: but can't you trim the CSS?

Comment: Minimising it has a minimal impact, but we do try and do it when we can.  Trimming it is something I'm doing at the moment to try and remove some of the redundancy, which was the reason for the question to know which direction to go in when doing this.

Comment: if the download time is the concern, you can gzip it and send it.. this surely improves the performance

Comment: Gzipping is definitely the way to go. Minifying will shave off a fair amount on a 3000-line file, but as soon as you gzip it, that difference is tiny. In other words, minify+gzip is never more than a few bytes smaller than gzip alone.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, if you split those 3k lines into multiple files the overall rendering time won't decrease because

1. All 3000 lines will still need to be parsed
2. Multiple requests are needed to get the CSS files which slows down the whole issue on another level

Comment: what if the styles were separated into different sections needed by the pages and only the pages that needed certain styles included those stylesheets?

Comment: Then it would help. Surely, if you only include what you need and you don't need all 3k lines every time, then it's good. Server-side collapsing of multiple files into one might help there too to reduce request count. But from the question it wasn't obvious that this might be the case (and, granted, I didn't think of it, originally).

Answer (score 15):

3,000 lines? You may want to first go in and look for redundancy, unnecessarily-verbose selectors, and other formatting/content issues. You can opt to create a text stylesheet, a colors stylesheet, and a layout stylesheet, but it's likely not going to improve performance. That is generally done to give you more organization. Once you've tightened up your rules, you could also minify it by removing all formatting, which might shave off a little bit more, but likely not much.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this probably reliable source](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/help/index.html#guidelines) one file, to satisfy rule 1 (minimize http requests).  And don't forget rule 10, minify js and css, especially with a 3000 line monster.

Comment: Maybe it's already minified and each of those *lines* is in the order of several thousand *characters* long :-)

Answer (score 5):

It'll be worse if you split them up because of the overhead of the extra HTTP requests andnew connections for each one (I *believe* it is Apache's default behaviour to have keep-alive off)

Either way, it all needs to be downloaded and parsed before anything can happen.

Answer (score 3):

Separating that monster file into smaller once (layout, format and so on) would make development more efficient. Before deployment you should merge and minify them to avoid multiple http requests. Giving the file a new number (style-x.css) for each new deployment will allow you to configure your http server to set an expire date far into the future and by that saving some additional http requests.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you are using CSS in a very inefficient way. I usually have a style sheet with between 400 and 700 lines and some of the sites that I have designed are very intricate. I don't think you should ever need more than 1500 lines, ever.

3000 lines of code is far to many to maintain properly. **My advice** would be to find things that share the same properties and make them sub-categories. For example, if you want to have one font throughout the page, define it once in the body and forget about it. If you need multiple fonts or multiple backgrounds you can put a div font1 and wrap anything that needs that font style with that div.

Always keep CSS in one file, unless you have completely different styles on each page.

Answer (score 2):

the effort of loading multiple css files stands against the complexity (and hence speed) of parsing as well as maintenance aspects

If certain subsets of the monster file can be related to certain html pages (and only those certain pages) then a separation into smaller units would make sense.

example:

you have a family homepage and your all.css contains all the formats for your own range of pages, your spouse's, your kids' and your pet's pages - all together 3000 lines.

```
./my/*.html     call ./css/all.css
./spouse/*.html call ./css/all.css
./kid/*.html    call ./css/all.css
./pet/*.html    call ./css/all.css
```

in this case it's rather easy to migrate to

```
./my/*.html     call ./css/my.css
./spouse/*.html call ./css/spouse.css
./kid/*.html    call ./css/kid.css
./pet/*.html    call ./css/pet.css
```

better to maintain, easier to transfer responsibilities, better to protect yourself from lousy code crunchers :-)

If all (or most) of your pages are sooo complex that they absolutely need the majority of the 3000 lines, then don't split. You may consider to check for "overcoding"

Good luck
MikeD

Answer (score 1):

The only gain in dividing your CSS would be to download each part in parallel. If you host each CSS on different server, it could in some case gain a bit of speed.

But in most case, having a single 3000 lines of code CSS should be (a bit) faster.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Yahoo performance rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html). They are backed by lots of empirical research.

Rule #1 is minimize HTTP requests (don't split the file--you could for maintenance purposes but for performance you should concat them back together as part of a build process). #5 is place CSS references at the top (in < head>). You can also use the [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) to reduce the file size of CSS by stripping whitespace etc.

More stuff (CDNs, gzipping, cache-control, etc.) in [the rules](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have a site css file that controls the styles for the overall site (layout mainly).

Then I have smaller css files for page specific stuff.

I even sometimes have more than one if I am planning on ripping out an entire section at a later date.

Better to download and parse 2 files at 20kb than 1 file at 200kb.

**Update:** Besides, isn't this a moot point? It only has to be downloaded once. If the pause is that big a deal, have a 'loading' screen like what GMail has.

Comment: Because having one massive file with the css for _every_ page means you are downloading redundant data. Splitting CSS into groups means you are only downloading the required styles for that page.

Answer (score 0):

3000 lines is not a big deal. If you split them into multiple chunks, it still needs to be downloaded  for rendering. the main concern is the file size. i have over 11000 lines in one of our master css file and the size is about 150 kb.

And we gzipped the static contents and the size is drastically reduced to about 20 kb.. and we didnt face any performance issues.