# Lots of small CSS files or one big one with sections - from a code-quality standpoint

Tags: css, structure, code-standards

I'm asking this question purely from an ease-of-development standpoint.

Performance is not a consideration, because we will have a build process that combines and compresses all our CSS files into a single file for release and then compresses it.

But which will be easier for a team of front-end developers to work with? Multiple files or a single file that is separated into distinct sections through comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [One massive CSS - or lots of little ones?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525107/one-massive-css-or-lots-of-little-ones)

Comment: Asked so many times before and they would have appeared when you were typing your question.

Comment: I know you said not for performance, but many answers here will be applicable: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128479/for-performance-use-one-or-several-css-files

Comment: Seriously, this is like the same title as the other one.

Comment: boy they came after you jon...
you chuds shouldn't downvote for a repeat question... advise him and move on smartly

Comment: @Hardryv when it's nearly the same title it seems warranted.

Comment: http://www.sadanduseless.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/696.jpg

Comment: This is NOT a repeat question. I'm asking it from a code-quality and ease-of-development standpoint not from a performance standpoint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525107/one-massive-css-or-lots-of-little-ones

Comment: @Pierreten, This is NOT a repeat question. I'm asking it from a code-quality and ease-of-development standpoint not from a performance standpoint.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3163183/lots-of-small-css-files-or-one-big-one-with-sections-from-a-code-quality-standp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're going to join and compress all the files at a later stage - I would most certainly split them into multiple files and organise them accordingly.

Check out how jQuery UI organise their CSS files, they have about 7 CSS files, and 1 main file which imports all 7 using the @import statement. This might be useful to you so you don't have to have 7 `<link rel="stylesheet" />` references.

Also make sure you order them accordingly so that any overrides are always at the bottom.

Good luck

Marko

Comment: Thanks Marco. I'll have a look at the jQuery files and how they're organized; they sound like a good setup to follow.

Comment: Your welcome - I found the files in my custom UI package in the folder development-bundle -> themes -> no-theme

Comment: but @import is not advisable for performance http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink